# Service B relies on data in Service A: Duplicate data or retrieve on-demand?

Tags: database, design-patterns, service, architecture, microservices

This is a microservice design question which is a simplification of a real-life problem I would like to solve.

Service A has entities which can be active or inactive.

```
[
    {
       id: "a46e6cc7-97ca-4570-b3f3-2be00ca9dab5",
       name: "foo",
       active: true
    },
    {
       id: "eb1ced31-eccc-4ad6-a695-5c6c76cab7a5",
       name: "bar",
       active: false
    },
    {
       id: "ef332044-9e66-4a0b-91ed-c16a2537e848",
       name: "baz",
       active: true
    }
]
```

Service B has jobs that are related to Service A's entities and should only run if the entities are active (according to business rule).

***Option 1:*** Service B does not store whether the jobs should run.

```
[
    {
       id: "39cf3321-34d1-4557-b1c4-ca628c191b92",
       entityId: ""a46e6cc7-97ca-4570-b3f3-2be00ca9dab5",
       start: "Thu Nov 29 2018 08:40:27 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)",
       ended: null,
       recurrence: "hourly"
    },
    {
       id: "77296d22-564f-4289-8327-f23bceb1d400",
       entityId: "a46e6cc7-97ca-4570-b3f3-2be00ca9dab5",
       start: "Tu Nov 27 2018 15:56:01 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)",
       ended: null,
       recurrence: "hourly"
    },
    {
       id: "2916a920-13a3-46f6-9ffd-d7629163924a",
       entityId: "eb1ced31-eccc-4ad6-a695-5c6c76cab7a5",
       start: "Wed April 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)",
       ended: Thu April 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time),
       recurrence: "daily"
    },
]
```

When a job is scheduled to run it checks

```
if Service A has j.entityId = true
   run j
```

using Service A's API.

***Option 2:*** Service B stores whether the job should run

```
[
    {
       id: "39cf3321-34d1-4557-b1c4-ca628c191b92",
       entityId: ""a46e6cc7-97ca-4570-b3f3-2be00ca9dab5",
       active: true,
       start: "Thu Nov 29 2018 08:40:27 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)",
       ended: null,
       recurrence: "hourly"
    },
    {
       id: "77296d22-564f-4289-8327-f23bceb1d400",
       entityId: "a46e6cc7-97ca-4570-b3f3-2be00ca9dab5",
       active: true,
       start: "Tu Nov 27 2018 15:56:01 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)",
       ended: null,
       recurrence: "hourly"
    },
    {
       id: "2916a920-13a3-46f6-9ffd-d7629163924a",
       entityId: "eb1ced31-eccc-4ad6-a695-5c6c76cab7a5",
       active: false,
       start: "Wed April 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)",
       ended: Thu April 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time),
       recurrence: "daily"
    },
]
```

Its storage is kept up-to-date by means of notification from Service A:

```
Entity e changes => publish e => Service B updates accordingly
```

Here are the arguments I see in favor of each option.

Option 1 arguments:

- Less storage cost since data is not duplicated
- When a job is scheduled to run it always has the most recent information about whether it should be active (more "consistency"?)
- Don't have to deal with complexity of syncing data across service. In this example there is only Service B that relies on data from A, but imagine the complexity if there were services X0, ..., X1000 that all needed to know whether an entity is active.

Option 2 arguments:

- The services are truly independent: If A is not running, B can still run
- Less chatty services (less network transfer cost)
- Although perhaps more complex, the complexity of duplicating/propagating data forces the services to share nothing or little

Comment: Option 2 doesn't seem to make the services independent. B is still coupled to A through the `entityId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should depend on your needs and how frequent the calls are, but before that few points that I would like to correct.

Cost of storage should really not be a concern, effort to keep data in sync and consequences thereafter are.
Chattiness is not bad, it may complicate things a bit, but there are ways you can get event driven system to do wonders and still be maintainable.

Services have to be independent, agree, but that does not mean they should not respect the boundaries. Order service needs to user data but that wont justify  keeping all user data in order service. It does not make it independent, but it simply bloats the service and make order worry about things that it should not really be concerned about.

So in your case, I will prefer to make api calls (and put up an SLA for the service A to respond fast, cache or whatever) but I would avoid to cache some one elses data in my system. 
However there are times when your service B is being invoked say some n times a minute and n is getting larger, then you might be inclined for approach b (but it will still be grey area and be cautious that it may make life difficult for you depending on how serviceA evolves over time)

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to create some real life situation to better understand:

We are working on youtube.

1. Service A manage a Entity which is User
2. Service B runs a job for each user - if user is active update user preferences using AI.

In this case it makes a lots of sense to just simple read the data from Service A (even though storing is not costly).

We should go with this as it is much simple to execute. Also if service A is down, temporarily this job will not run is also ok for the business.

Now in another business case:

Lets try to create some real life situation to better understand:

We are working on youtube.

1. Service A manage a Entity which is User
2. Service B - if user become inactive send a email notification.

This surely I would like to implement using events.

**Now my main point use eventing generally when you want to reactive do some operations and dependencies are low.
Otherwise read the data from the main service as it is simple and managing the data in another service (which soon could become multiple Service B's) will create problem in managing**